Indecomposable complex finite dimensional representations of a compact Lie group are Irreducibles?
I am studying the book "Representations of Compact Lie Groups" by Theodor Brocker and Tammo tom Dieck. At page 68 they prove the following proposition:
Let $G$ be a compact group. If $V$ is a submodule of the $G$-module $U$, then there is a complementary submodule $W$ such that $U$ is the direct sum of $V$ and $W$. Each $G$-module is a direct sum of irreducible submodules.
where they use the word $G$-module for a complex finite dimensional representations of $G$.
The proof is very short but it seems to me that they avoid the case when $U$ is indecomposable. Is there something I'm missing? Indecomposable complex finite dimensional representations of a compact Lie group are Irreducibles?

yes it is true, the proof uses averaging over the group to get a $G$-invariant complement

I've seen it for finite groups but I was wondering if it exists a simple proof of this also for my case

The proof should spit out the fact that every finite-dimensional $G$-module is completely decomposable into irreducible ones, simply by unitarizing the representation (averaging the inner product with respect to the action of the compact group [compact -> integral converges]) and then inductively splitting the representation into smaller ones until they are all irreducible (possible since we assumed finite dimension, so the process terminates)

Thank you for your patience but the last thing I dont understand is why this process needs to give smaller representations till they are irreducible and can't get an indecomposible one in the direct sum. This is probably dumb but I can't see it.

@Don: the process terminates once the representations no longer have (proper nonzero) subrepresentations, which is the definition of irreducibility. In particular, yes, indecomposable representations are irreducible, because if they were reducible they'd have (proper nonzero) subrepresentations which would have complements.
